# Will a win 8 OEM on a win 7 OEM

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ssd, oem, license-key

When I bought my hardware it was shipped with `Windows 7 Professional`. After a while I got an offer to upgrade and purchase a Windows 8 OEM license.

Now comes the question, is it possible to use this Windows 8 OEM CD on a blank SSD (I have changed discs to new ssd in the mashine) and during the installation of Windows 8 imput the product key for the orginal Windows 7 OEM license as proof of having and original OEM license as base for the upgrade?

Comment: Depends if the license is a `Windows 8 System Builder` license or a `Windows 8 Upgrade` license.  You need to clarify what you mean by Windows 8 OEM exactly, if you purchased it through an OEM, then your migration rights are extremely limited.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 8 (OEM) setup disk will happily accept your Windows 8 product key - there is no need for the Windows 7 disk or key. The limited "Windows Upgrade Offer" by Microsoft gives you (technically) a full version of Windows; the existence of a eligable copy of Windows 7 has been checked at the time you bought it. There is no technical check on you key or dirc later.